# How to know which dropdownlist onchange event was triggerd in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

Im trying to do a rather simple practice project and i got stuck for a while now.

I have 3 dropdownlists
and 3 views.

I want to do:
check if the current dropdownlist has chosen a value then that dropdown has a value, hide that view and show the next view.

my problem:
I have one method for all 3 of my dropdownlists that gets called when a change occurs.
I need to check which one of these dropdownlists triggerd the change so that i know which dropdownlist value i need to check(if it is empty or not) and depending on the value i show/hide views.

If more info is needed just ask and Thanks!

Comment: Just to add a quick comment, i know that this can be done very efficeintly via script but i want to learn how to do it using only asp.net. Again if anything is unclear: I need to know how to get the dropdownlist ID of the list that trigged the change event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the function you probably have something like

```
protected void OnChangedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // code here
}
```

`sender` contains the dropdown list that fired the event. So:

```
protected void OnChangedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
}
```

and `ddl` will be the dropdown list.

Comment: damn it when i saw this i was kind of hoping it was wrong...my first attempt was actually sender.ID but I did not realize that i hade to cast it to a DropDownList...:( 2 hours of my life vent out the window just like that.

Thank alot!